# AngularCLI error on Mac, getColorDepth not a function

Tags: angular, macos, command-line-interface

On MacOS, Mojave 10.14.5, using Angular CLI 8.3.7, I get this error:

```
ng build


/Projects/AngularTest/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/color.js:15
    process.stdout.getColorDepth() > 1;
                   ^

TypeError: process.stdout.getColorDepth is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (Projects/AngularTest/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/color.js:15:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Projects/AngularTest/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/analytics.js:18:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
```

This is after installing latest cli and creating a new project.  Haven't made any code changes, just tried to build it.

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the Nodejs version to greater than 9.9

[Check below link](https://github.com/power-assert-js/empower/issues/28)